# Как добавить данные в буфер DMA и отуда передать данные в uart?

Tags: linux, c

Мне нужно формировать сообщение не больше 20 байт добавить сообщение в буфер DMA
отправить его по UART(ttyS4) получить информацию что сообщение передано с буфера DMA. Использую одноплатный компьютер BeagleBone ос Ubuntu 18.04. Подскажите как делать с чего начать использую С. 
Вот код отправки сообщений

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "unistd.h"

int open_port()
{
    int fd; 
    fd = open("/dev/ttyS4", O_RDWR  | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY | O_SYNC);
    if (fd == -1)
    {   
        perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyS4 - ");
    }
    else
    {
        fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
        printf("Ok - Port open!\n");
    }
    return (fd);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int fd;
    fd = open_port();
    int n; /* Количество посланных байт(write) */
    char buf[] = "qwertyuiop\n"; /* Буффер ввода */
    int length; /* Длина строки ввода (Количество байт) */

length = sizeof(buf) / sizeof(char);
n = write(fd, buf, length);

if (n == -1) 
{
    fputs("Error write!\n", stderr);
}
else
{
    printf("Great %d bait(a) \n", n);
}
close(fd);

printf("Ok - Port Close!\n\n");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Если драйвер вам не гарантирует этого, то никак.

Comment: как это определить?

Comment: Читать код драйвера. Если сил и энергии хватит, то дня за три найдёте ответ на вопрос. И поймите одну штуку, что это будет лишь для конкретного драйвера на конкретном устройстве, для другого устройства и/или драйвера может быть иначе.

Comment: То есть стандарта DMA под системы которые используют Linux?

Comment: Я не понял ваш вопрос-комментарий.